# TFS 2010 add solution to source control not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, source-control-bindings

I'm facing a strange problem: I have a new installation of TFS 2010 on a test machine and I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional on a client machine. My client was before configured to be connected with another TFS 2010 machine with the same bindings. Now, from my client machine I manage to create Team projects in the default collection, but nothing is happening when I try to add a solution to source control. It means that when I physically push the button "Add solution to source control" no window or message is showing.
Of course I set all the permissions and group memberships on the server machine, and I restarted client and server several times.
How can I solve (or at least make a diagnosys) the problem?

Comment: Was the solution bound to another TFS before?

Comment: Navigate to "File">"Source Control">"Change source control.." What are you getting there?

Comment: yes the solution was bound to another TFS. I removed all the bindings and already went to "Change souce control". The problem is that now i need to bind the solution to a new tfs but nothing is happening!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you also removed the workspace from the old TFS? Workspace mappings cannot be shared across multiple TFS instances.

Comment: what do you mean? The old TFS is gone (forever!) so I will not have the possibility to do anything. I want just to clean up my solutions (the local ones) from any binding and add them to the new TFS. But something is blocking this! Nothing is shown when I click "add solution to source control". I even try to add to source control a solution with the same name but the system does not let me do it. Adding a solution with a new name goes fine. Is that some kind of setting in my Visual Studio client installation that has recorded something from the old TFS and does not let me do anything?

Comment: I think there is still a workspace for your old TFS which you should delete. Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and execute `tf workspaces` to check which workspaces are available and delete the old with `tf workspace /delete [/server:servername] workspacename[;workspaceowner]`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: To take the client cache of workspaces out of the picture, you can run tf workspaces /remove:* /collection:* and that will clear your cache.  VS will re-populate the cache when you connect to your new TFS server.  I'm not sure that's it, but it would at least be one less thing that could be interfering.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Team Explorer installed?  Is TFS set as the default source control provider in Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Current source control plug-in?